# Symfony2 service parameters - passing the current request

Tags: service, request, symfony

I want to create a service in Symfony2 that will take in the current request on the constructor and use it to determine the type of browser used for the request.

I can create the class and define it as a service but how do I pass in the current request using the XML service definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just use the `request` service. This however requires your service to be declared with `scope="request"`. Another approach i used was to inject the service-container and retrieve the `request`-Service form there when you need it.

Comment: Didn't know about `scope="request"`.  Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you use the `request` service?