# Access request parameter in form type for modify form dynamically

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have two Symfony2 different forms: one for register common users with fields that belongs only to a User type and the second one for register company and again with fields that belongs only to Company types (both have different fields) so they relies on FOSUserBundle User class which means they extends from FOSUser. I should be add the ability for users (common users that navigates trough the site) to register as a `User` and as a `Company` and for that I made a simple SELECT element with both choices.

I need to change "dynamically" the form types for FOSUser Registration but can't find a good approach and this is why I ask for help.

This is what I have in mind, maybe some crazy ideas and maybe the worst, but is the only I can find as my knowledge is.

1. Change the registration class "dynamically" at `config.yml`(tough is not a good idea since I'll need to reload the page in order to changes take effect or don't)

   ```
   services:
       user.registration.form.type:
           class: UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
           arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
           tags:
               - { name: form.type, alias: user_form }

   fos_user:
       registration:
           form:
               type: user_form
   ```
2. Generate forms based on user data as explain [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data) in docs but this should be build on two step form, right? One for select the form type and the second for show/display the form? How to do this then using FOSUserBundle?

Right now I'm just calling the `RegistrationFormType` which have common fields from FOSUser among others but dinamically I need to add new forms, any idea or approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect an onchange on your select element and do an AJAX request to get the right form ?
Then, get the form by the method called with AJAX. Set the FormType as service, pass the request as argument ([Symfony2 service parameters - passing the current request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644708/symfony2-service-parameters-passing-the-current-request) and here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request), and build your form ?

Comment: and see here also, maybe that can help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293816/symfony-2-service-parameters